# Can't mount sshfs directory at login

Tags: login, sshfs, user-profile

I want to automatically mount a `sshfs` directory at login.
So I add this line to the end of my otherwise ok profile:

```
/usr/bin/sshfs he@192.168.1.118:/klipp klipp
```

This however results in

```
Error found when loading /home/he/.profile
```

and no mounted directory. SSH trust is established with `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The command works without a glitch if issued after login.
Thanks for any tip.

Comment: I'd try to insert the complete path of the mount point. For example: **/usr/bin/sshfs he@192.168.1.118:/klipp /home/he/klipp**

Comment: Thanks, now it works.     
H

Comment: @user.dz ok, done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to insert the complete path of the mount point. For example:

```
/usr/bin/sshfs he@192.168.1.118:/klipp /home/he/klipp
```